# JavaScript, every loop define a variable as the first item in a list, then the next etc

Tags: javascript

Java script,
I have a list, animals = [cat, dog, another_cat, another_dog, mouse, squirrel, etc.]

and another list, numbers = [2, 3, 4]

I am looping the animals list.
for( i = 0; i < animals.length; i++)
console.log = (numbers)

I need "console.log = (numbers)" on the first loop to give me 2, on the next one to give me 3, next 4, next 2...3...4

I apologize again if I wasn't clear.

Comment: `for (let bla of list) { ... }`

Comment: you can use `const`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the remainder operator (`%`) and the length of the array to calculate.

```js
const animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'another_cat', 'another_dog', 'mouse', 'squirrel'];

const numbers = [2, 3, 4];

for (let i = 0, counter = 0 ; counter < animals.length; ++counter) {
    console.log(`number: ${numbers[i]}, animal: ${animals[counter]}`);
    i = (i + 1) % numbers.length;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the elaborate answer, but I guess my question wasn't clear, let me rephrase it.

I have a list, animals = [cat, dog, another_cat, another_dog, mouse, squirrel, etc.]

and another list, numbers = [2, 3, 4]

I am looping the animals list.
for( i = 0; i < animals .length; i++)
 {console.log = (numbers)
}

I need "console.log = (numbers)" on the first loop to give me 2, on the next one to give me 3, next 4, next 2...3...4

I apologize again if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Hi @Adrian I re-edited my answer, you can refer to it again